# Синтаксис и пунктуация

Tags: синтаксис

В каком из трёх предложений придаточная часть начинается с союзного слова:
  1.Я верю, что ничто не проходит бесследно...
  2.Анна оказалась гораздо приятнее, чем думала о ней Кити.
  3.Не всякий услышит, как звезды звенят.

Answer (score 2):

Не всякий услышит, как звезды звенят. Это СПП с придаточным изъяснительным, в котором союзное КАК является обстоятельством образа действия.